# Regular Expression for a specific set of words in a sentence

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I would like some assistance with creating a regular expression that could locate a specific set of word(s) within a sentence. The specific set of words or word is known before we search the sentence. These words will always exist within the sentence. The set will be expanding as time goes by. Examples below,

Set of words: "**of the house**", "**time**", "**this is how**", "**coming**", "**home**"

Sentences that should return a match:

1) "I was coming out **of the house**" -> Match for "**of the house**"

2) "I remember the **time** when I used to be a baby" -> Match for "**time**"

3) "Well, I am not sure what you did, but **this is how** I fix my problems" -> Match for "**this is how**"

4) "When are you coming **home**?" -> Match for "**home**"

**UPDATE:** The language of implementation will be in PHP

Comment: A simple combination `"of the house|time|this is how|coming|home"` should work, what's the problem?

Comment: What's the flavor/tool?

Comment: @acdcjunior probably PHP, i.e. PCRE (due to the `preg-match` tag)

Comment: I apologize for omitting the language. It will be in submitted to a PHP API

Answer (score 2):

## Description

This expression will match the your phrases, and ensure they are not embedded inside another larger word.

`^.*?(?:\s|^)(of\sthe\shouse|time|this\sis\show|home)(?=\W|$).*`

[image]

## PHP Code Example:

You didn't specify a language so I'm just providing this php example to simply show how this works.

**Sample Text**

```
1) "I was coming out of the house"
2) "I remember the time when I used to be a baby"
3) "Well, I am not sure what you did, but this is how I fix my problems"
4) "When are you coming home?"
5) "This is howard Timey said of the houseboat"
6) "The last word in this line is home
```

**Code**

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/^.*?(?:\s|^)(of\sthe\shouse|time|this\sis\show|home)(?=\W|$).*/imx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1) "I was coming out of the house"
        [1] => 2) "I remember the time when I used to be a baby"
        [2] => 3) "Well, I am not sure what you did, but this is how I fix my problems"
        [3] => 4) "When are you coming home?"
        [4] => 6) "The last word in this line is home
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => of the house
        [1] => time
        [2] => this is how
        [3] => home
        [4] => home
    )
```

Comment: `[\W\s\r\n]` is the same as `\W`. Also, this will not work if the string ends with the keyword. (because the lookahead requires a character there) I'd just use a word boundary at both ends.

Comment: now `(?=\W|$)` in the given case is entirely equivalent to (though less efficient than) `\b`. but at least it works now. +1